# Rename git branch name on remote using PyGithub

Tags: python-3.x, pygithub

How can I rename **github** remote branch using `PyGithub` python API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference from official PyGithub - https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub
https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis.html

```py
from github import Github

# using username and password
g = Github("user", "password")

# or using an access token
g = Github("access_token")

# get repo
r = g.get_organization('org').get_repo('name')

# Git reference of the branch that you wish to delete
src = r.get_git_ref("heads/source branch name")

# Create new branch from old branch
r.create_git_ref("refs/heads/new branch name", sha=src.object.sha)

# Delete old branch reference
src.delete()
```